# Opening a .tex file on Windows emacs 25.1

Tags: latex, auctex, microsoft-windows

When I try and open a .tex file on emacs 25.1 under Windows I now get this error:

```
File mode specification error: (dbus-error No connection to bus :session)
```

And cannot typeset anything using the usual `C-c C-c` command.

I think it may be something to with trying to load auctex because if I start emacs with -Q and open a tex file it opens OK.

Does anyone have a clue how to fix that?  It works fine on emacs 24.5.1

Comment: D-Bus is used only for the Evince viewer, unless you use it I can't understand why D-Bus is invoked at all.  I suggest you to report this problem to the AUCTeX but tracker, issue `M-x TeX-submit-bug-report RET` after opening a TeX file.  Please, be as much descriptive as possible.

Comment: Thanks very much for the pointer there - it turns out my emacs was buiilt without the --without-dbus option, which was causing the problem!

Comment: You can post an answer explaining the culprit, so it'll be useful also to other users ;-)